# How to make more suitable for a fragment

Tags: java, android

```
    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.Q)
    public void onViewCreated() {

        recyclerView = recyclerView.findViewById(R.id.nowplayinglist);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity().getApplicationContext()));

        int permissionCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);

        if (permissionCheck == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            setupUI();
        } else {

            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                new String[] {
                    Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
                },
                CALL);
        }
    }
```

How do I change the activitycompat and contextcompat to be more suitable for a fragment rather than an activity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to replace `this` keyword with `requireActivity()` as it should refer to an `Activity` instead of a `Fragment`

So update your code to be:

```
int permissionCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(requireActivity(),
        Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);

ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(requireActivity(),
         new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
         CALL);
```